# Monitor connected via DisplayPort randomly blanking out for a second when other monitors are fine

Tags: display, displayport

I understand poor quality cables or cables being too long can cause this behavior. I have 3 monitors (all different brands/sizes) running at 2560x1440 with some passive switches involved. I upgraded all my cables (most are now 16K rated, others 8K) and 2 of the monitors seem to be solid now, but one keeps blanking out rather often. I have switched cables around and the 2 monitors stay stable, but the one keeps having the issue, so it seems something about that particular monitor is susceptible to this issue. If I hook it up straight to the computer, it doesn't have this problem, so the monitor is capable. If I fiddle with things, unplug/replug cables/power, sometimes it seems to get better, but I haven't found anything consistent.

My question: Are there things that might help with this other than changing the cabling, resolution, or replacing it?

DisplayPort signal booster?
DisplayPort to HDMI adapter (monitor has both inputs)?
Monitor settings?
Something else?

Comment: Which monitor is this? How long is the cable?

Comment: I think it's a Dell P2418D. The cable is: computer -> 6 foot -> switch -> 6 foot -> monitor.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there are other solutions (still interested in learning more), but I ended up purchasing a DisplayPort 1.4 repeater and putting that in the line: PC -> 6 foot -> switch -> 6 foot -> repeater -> 6 foot -> monitor. The second and third cables could be a lot shorter, but that's the cables I had. It has been running solid since with no black screen or flicker.